# Double Animation, .stop() Not Fixing It

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For some reason, I can't figure out how to stop the double animation in the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var activeNews = "01";
        $(".newsNav.forward").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (activeNews == 01) {
                $(".newsItem.01").stop(true, true).fadeOut(250, function() {
                    $(".newsItem.02").stop(true, true).fadeIn(250);
                });
                activeNews = 02;
            } else if (activeNews == 02) {
                $(".newsItem.02").stop(true, true).fadeOut(250, function() {
                    $(".newsItem.03").stop(true, true).fadeIn(250);
                });
                activeNews = 03;
            } else if (activeNews == 03) {
                $(".newsItem.03").stop(true, true).fadeOut(250, function() {
                    $(".newsItem.01").stop(true, true).fadeIn(250);
                });
                activeNews = 01;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When you click on `.newsNav.forward` too quickly, multiple `.newsItems` appear, instead of just one. As you can see, I'm aware that `.stop();` is supposed to fix this, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

HTML if it's relevant:

```
<div id="news">
    <a class="newsNav back" href="#">&lt;</a>
    <a class="newsNav forward" href="#">&gt;</a>
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
    <div id="newsSlider">
        <p class="newsItem 01 active">First News Item</p>
        <p class="newsItem 02">Second News Item</p>
        <p class="newsItem 03">Third News Item</p>
    </div><!--/#newsSlider-->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div><!--/#news-->
```

Relevant CSS as well:

```
#contentWrapper #content #news #newsSlider p.newsItem {
        display: none;
    }

    #contentWrapper #content #news #newsSlider p.newsItem.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're only stopping one animation at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only stopping the animation of certain classes. To achieve a "global" stop in animation, you will have to clear the animation queue for all elements that will be potentially animated in your JS function.

This will mean doing something along the line of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeNews = "01";
    $(".newsNav.forward").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Pre-emptively stops all animation
        $(".newsItem").stop(true, true);

        // Note the removal of the .stop() method before each animation
        if (activeNews == 01) {
            $(".newsItem.01").fadeOut(250, function() {
                $(".newsItem.02").fadeIn(250);
            });
            activeNews = 02;
        } else if (activeNews == 02) {
            $(".newsItem.02").fadeOut(250, function() {
                $(".newsItem.03").fadeIn(250);
            });
            activeNews = 03;
        } else if (activeNews == 03) {
            $(".newsItem.03").fadeOut(250, function() {
                $(".newsItem.01").fadeIn(250);
            });
            activeNews = 01;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My bad, left out the parameters when I was typing in my answer. Fixed.